# REST Handling a Bad Parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

What is the proper way to handle a bad parameter in a RESTful service?  I have an endpoint right now that returns a 400 if the wrong data type is sent.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/test")
public MyResponse getSomething(@RequestParam BigDecimal bd) {
    MyResponse r = new MyResponse();
    r.setBd(bd);
    return r;
}
```

It would be really nice if the end user were to pass, say, a String instead of a BigDecimal, that the response would return a json with the response code, status, and whatever else I'd like it to contain, rather than just a 400.  Is there a way to do this?

Update:  My initial thought was to wrap every parameter and then check to see if it's the correct type in that wrapper class.  This seems a bit silly.  Isn't there a validator that I could just add to the classpath that would recognize something like this?

Also, there is a way to handle this quite easily with a Bean type that I could create on my own, but what about standard types like BigDecimal?

**UPDATE-2:  This update addresses answer that uses @ExceptionHandler.**

**TestController.java**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    //this is where correct input from user is passed, no binding errors
    @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/test")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    MyResponse getSomething(@RequestParam BigDecimal bd) {
        MyResponse r = new MyResponse();
        r.setBd(bd);
        return r;
    }

    //this will handle situation when you except number and user passess string (A123.00 for example)
    @ExceptionHandler(ServletRequestBindingException.class)
    public @ResponseBody MyErrorResponse handleMyException(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {

        MyErrorResponse r = new MyErrorResponse();
        r.setEexception(exception);

        return r;
    }


}
```

**TestUnitTest.java**

```
public class TestUnitTest {

protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}


@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String url =  "/v1/test?bd=a123.00";

    log.info("Testing Endpoint::: " + url);

    MvcResult result =  mockMvc.perform(get(url))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andReturn();

    log.info("RESPONSE::: " + result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}

}
```

**MyResponse.java**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MyResponse {

    private BigDecimal bd;

    public BigDecimal getBd() {
        return bd;
    }

    public void setBd(BigDecimal bd) {
        this.bd = bd;
    }

}
```

**MyErrorResponse.java**

```
public class MyErrorResponse {

    private Exception exception;

    public Exception getException() {
        return exception;
    }

    public void setEexception(Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spring `@ExceptionHandler` along with standard `@RequestMapping` annotation like this:

```
//this is where correct input from user is passed, no binding errors
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/v1/test")
public
@ResponseBody
MyResponse getSomething(@RequestParam BigDecimal bd) {
    MyResponse r = new MyResponse();
    r.setBd(bd);
    return r;
}

//this will handle situation when there's exception during binding, for example you except number and user passess string (A123.00 for example)
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
public 
@ResponseBody
MyErrorResponse handleMyException(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //....
}
```

`TypeMismatchException` is general exception thrown when trying to set a bean property. You can generalize code even more and catch every binding exception with few methods, for example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
public
@ResponseBody
String typeMismatchExpcetionHandler(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "type mismatch";
}

@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
public
@ResponseBody
String missingParameterExceptionHandler(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "missing param";
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public
@ResponseBody
String generalExceptionHandler(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "general exception";
}
```

It's very flexible, allowing many parameters in signature and returned objects [Annotation Type ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

With `@ResponseBody` you may return any object, that can be serialized into JSON. It's only required to have jackson library in your classpath but I assume that you already know this

Comment: This would be great if I had an exception to pass it.  My case I believe is different.  I'd like to be able to validate the parameters passed to the RESTful service.  If you believe I can still use this, would you mind giving an example?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. So you want to allow user to pass anything and then validate it? `@ExceptionHandler` is called when there's exception thrown for example during binding parameters (when you except number and string is passed etc.), when you get to `@RequestMapping` it means that binding was correct and you may validate. Could you explain a lil' bit more?

Comment: In the above example I have, the method should take a BigDecimal.  But if the end user passes A123.00, it returns a 400 (the mistake being that there's an 'A' in front of 123.00).  I am coming to the conclusion that you can't do this unless you wrap the data type, as Sotirios is suggesting...

Comment: Well you missing something here. It's spring that throws exception for you, so I believe my solution should help you. Just  create and ordinar RequestMapping along with ExceptionHandler and see the results. I'll update answer

Comment: Thank you so far, kamil.  I've updated my post to show everything I'm doing.  Still there is no validation happening, just a 400 returned.

Comment: Well, thanks to you I finally tried spring-boot, for rapid web app creation :) In your case, you should catch `TypeMismatchException` for binding exceptions. I'll update my answer